# Are there are widely accepted criteria on when a fund is under-performing enough to exit it?

Tags: india, mutual-funds

I'm told that once I invest in a fund, I should periodically (like annually) monitor the performance of the fund and exit it if it's consistently under-performing its index or the median fund in its category. If not, I don't want to churn my portfolio.

Now, are there any widely accepted criteria on when a fund is under-performing enough that you should exit it? A fund can under-perform in one year, so that's not a good criterion. Two years?

And to what extent is under-performance allowed? Maybe if a fund loses 10% in the first year when the index went up 10%, you'd immediately exit it, rather than giving it another year?

Are there any norms for this?

This is with reference to India, if it matters.

Comment: Obligatory Will Rogers quote: "Don't gamble; take all your savings and buy some good stock and hold it till it goes up, then sell it. If it don't go up, don't buy it."

Comment: That's neither useful nor funny :)